# How to display a list of git commits which are actually contributing into diff between two branches?

Tags: git, branch, diff, commit

Let's say there are two branches `a` and `b` in a git repository.

At the tip of branch a there's `foo.txt`:

```
111
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

while at the tip of branch `b` same `foo.txt` is like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
222
```

Consider lines `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc` where introduced in three different commits, one per line for branch b. And same lines where introduced in a single commit for branch a. So the only difference which is displayed by `git diff a b` is in line `111` and `222`.

Is there any simple way to display only commits responsible for actual diff between branches, while omitting commits respondible for `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use something like a tool I wrote for this kind of request called `difflame` that joins information from diff and blame.

https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yep, that's just what I needed. I'll try to make a Python3 port later.